# Why lightmap_pack change uv1 and uv 2

Tags: python, uv

I'm a new python developer. Recently I want to make a script to add a new UV for model and using lightmap_pack to unwrap. it works great but i found the uv1 is changed with lightmap_pack. Why?

```
import bpy
from random import random 
from math import radians
import sys
import os  
import os.path
import string
context = bpy.context
objects = bpy.context.scene.objects 
for obj in objects : 
    if obj.type == 'MESH':   
        context.view_layer.objects.active = obj 
        obj.select_set(state=True)
        mesh = obj.data   
        if len(mesh.uv_layers) < 2:
            mesh.uv_layers.new(name='lm')
            lm = mesh.uv_layers.get('lm')
            bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
            lm.active = True  
            bpy.ops.uv.lightmap_pack() 
            bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle() 
print('start to export')
```

Edit:
I found that if the mesh have child mesh, the parent mesh uv2 and uv1 will changed at same time,
but is there is only one mesh lightmap_pack will only affact uv2.

How to deal with this?

Comment: Using `lm = mesh.uv_layers.get('lm') or mesh.uv_layers.new(name='lm')`  will give you the old one if it exists, or a new one named "lm".  The way it is above will keep adding "lm.001" , "lm.002" , ...but you will always only be operating on  "lm".

Comment: I'm tried to this ：lm =mesh.uv_layers.new(name='lm.'+str(meshIndex)) 
meshIndex+=1  but it's same result.

Comment: if the mesh have child mesh, add a uv2 for each mesh and use lightmap_pack to unwrap. the parent mesh's uv1 and uv2 will changed. i only want to change uv2's unwrap.

Comment: My point being If you want to use the new one use `lm = mesh.uv_layers.new(name='lm') ` there is no need to "get" it as well  Its name will depend on the existance of "lm", "lm.001" etc. .  To make sure it is the one named "lm" use get and if its None use new.  The way you have it in question code is wrong.  This  explains why first one is the one always being used. Re the child mesh, edit question.  In particular explain what you mean by uv1 and uv2 (i assume it's where they are in uvmaps collection? .. where first is `uv1 = uv_layers[0]`?

Comment: `import bpy  
context = bpy.context
objects = bpy.context.scene.objects 
 
for obj in objects : 
    if obj.type == 'MESH':   
       context.view_layer.objects.active = obj 
       obj.select_set(state=True)
       mesh = obj.data   
       if len(mesh.uv_layers) < 2: 
           lm = mesh.uv_layers.new(name='lm')
           lm.active = True
           bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
           bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="SELECT")
           bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(island_margin=0.05)
           bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
           lm.active = True
`